# how to raise a fault in apigee flow and redirect it to a javascript error handling script

Tags: exception, apigee

i have a flow

```
<Request>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>GUDExtractVariablesRequest</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>GUDAssignMessageOutbound</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>GUDExecuteOutboundRequest</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>GUDTokenUseFail</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <Name>GUDparseResponse</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>GUDAssignMsgIDM</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>createurlforGUD</Name>
            </Step>
```

GUDTokenUseFail is a fault i raised i need to redirect it to a javascript file which will handle all the errors and respond back accordingly. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a section in your proxy like below.

```
   <FaultRules>
        <FaultRule name="defaultFaultHandling">
            <Step>
                <Name>your-js-policy1</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <Name>your-other-policy2</Name>
                <Condition>some.var = "true"</Condition>
            </Step>
        </FaultRule>
    </FaultRules>
```